# Trying to pull Data from one sheet into another sheet based on Criteria defined

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to Vba & Excel as a whole. I have two Worksheets (Sheet 1 & Sheet 2):

**Sheet 1** contains information like Name (Full Name) and a Graded score (Grades). Each name has a grade tied to it.

**Sheet 2** has cells that represent a grade range. I am trying to pull the names of the employees which meet a certain grade into their respective boxes.

Examples - If John Doe and Jane Doe has a grading of "Exceeds A" on Sheet 1. Sheet 2 should carry their name listed in the same column under the "Exceeds A" field name.

I hope I explained this well enough. I attached a picture of the ranges for better understanding:

[image: Sheet 2 Range]

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub Grades()

    Dim rng As Range, rngGrades As Range, cll As Range
    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, iLastCell As Integer

    ' Assuming Sheet2 is set up in the following format:
    ' Grade | Grade | Grade
    '       |       |
    ' Grade | Grade | Grade
    '       |       |
    ' Grade | Grade | Grade
    '       |       |
    ' Can be adjusted if different
    Set rng = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1:C6")

    ' It's not specified how the data is structured on Sheet1
    ' Assuming that names are in column A and grades in column B
    iLastCell = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Column

    With Sheets("Sheet1")
        Set rngGrades = .Range(.Cells(2, 2), (.Cells(2, iLastCell)))
    End With

    For i = 1 To 5 Step 2
        For j = 1 To 3
            For Each cll In rngGrades
                If cll.Value2 = rng(i, j) Then
                    rng(i + 1, j).Value2 = rng(i + 1, j).Value2 & vbLf & Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, cll.Column)
                End If
            Next
        Next
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Michal, the Data is Sheet 1 is structured this way. The name are listed in Each letter column. Example B1 is John Doe, C1 'Jane Doe', D1 'Tom Tommy'. Their grades with is a String are listed below their record. Example B2 grading for John Doe is 'Exceeds B'. C2 for Jane Doe reads 'Meets B'. D2 for Tom Tommy reads 'Below B'.. Does this code still work ? Or do i need to change some parameters ?. Thank you so much

Comment: I've changed as per your description but you really should have tried doing it yourself first :)  Cheers,